# Why interviewers ask algorithm questions even if job position doesn't require such knowledge?

Tags: interviewing, developer

I have seen lot of interviewers asking advance algorithm and data structure questions while job doesn't require any knowledge of them. It is true for a lot of times so why interviewers ask such questions?

Comment: What sort of programming jobs don't require knowledge of algorithms and data structures?  Without those basics all you can do is thoughtlessly copy data around.  You can't even design a good data model.

Comment: @kevincline most web development in standard website shops for example.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum What web development job doesn't require knowledge of algorithms and data structures? My wife runs a furniture store online, but when she wanted to make the tiniest changes to the store template templates she had to learn about associative arrays. Luckily she's pretty smart and it only took a few minutes, but she still had to know what was going on.

Comment: Associative arrays aren't "knowing data structures", your wife didn't have to spend a minute thinking about the backing hash table or red black tree. That's the beauty of it :)

Comment: For many there's a simple answer: they do it because Google does it.

Comment: I'm weeping for the industry right now.

Comment: @Benjamin: There's plenty of room for gross inefficiency in client-side Javascript.  I've seen it many times.  If you meant "writing HTML and CSS", that's graphic design, not programming.

Comment: It's a test of how recently you were a CS undergrad.

Comment: Because it is required for the job.

Comment: @GlenPierce not really its more because its trendy

Comment: @Neuromancer, I agree, because it's trendy. Just last year, tech companies had me develop small applications for them, now they all give me Codility and Hackerrank algorithms and send me on my way and no they do not ask me to explain my solutions. So I call bullocks on that one. They just look to see if I have 100%, no? ok, on to the next sorry bloke with a resume.

Comment: One very last and glaring point we all seem to miss. In any other industry, if you are asked to prove you can do something, it was already outlined in the job description(for the most part). So, either place **needs to know algorithms** in the job description OR **must have CS degree**. Testing someone on something that you did not ask for in a job description rings false when you leave out the elegant justification that kolossus gave. In laymans terms, its called being blind-sided.

Answer (score 30):

It's mostly a test of your understanding of the fundamentals of Computer Science (which should be a prerequisite for any programmer).

Software development has evolved to the point where the fundamentals of building good product have been abstracted away from the average developer. "High-level" languages have bred a new crop of copy-n-paste programmers that don't know *why* it's working, only that it does. While it's not easy, almost anyone can learn an API nowadays.

Asking about algorithms, data structures and design patterns helps a lot of companies weed out the programmers that can raid Stackoverflow for good answers, without understanding the operating principles behind them. You'll also find that many companies that ask about such fundamentals, build in a variety of platforms. Rather than ask for things peculiar to a specific language/platform, they'll open the interview with more general computer science questions.

Knowing the fundamentals of CS helps you make better higher level decisions when programming. If I were an employer, I'd want to recruit a programmer that knows the difference between a Stack and a Queue; a ArrayList from a LinkedHashSet; Bubble sort from Quick Sort; There are performance/design implications for these decisions. It's important to understand them, rather than just ripping something off the net (by an author that may have made the wrong decision without your understanding/knowledge). Knowing the solution is not understanding the solution

Comment: Why don't OS's, compilers,...? Why just algorithms?

Comment: ... but why? If you absolutely don't need to know the fundamentals, why would they ask it? (I'm not saying you shouldn't, just that you didn't really give a reason in your answer.) There are also other reasons why they'd ask such questions.

Comment: @VarunAgw - OS's and Compilers are ultimately built on what? Algorithms. Data Structures. Logic.  Fundamentals. That's what everything programming ultimately boils down to. Rather than split hairs between C# and Java, I'd rather ask you questions based on something they both have in common

Comment: @Dukeling - If I were an employer, I'd want to recruit a programmer that knows the difference between a Stack and a Queue; a ArrayList from a LinkedHashSet; Bubble sort from Quick Sort; Threads vs Processes. There are performance/design implications for these decisions. Better understand than just rip something off the net that may have made the wrong decision without your understanding/knowledge. Knowing the solution is not understanding the solution. I'm not saying that you must understand the solution 100% of the time, but as an employer, I'd be happier to shell out the bucks if you did.

Comment: @kolossus That should probably go into your answer.

Comment: @Dukeling - I'm quite sure I gave multiple reasons, along the lines of "..weed out the programmers that can raid Stackoverflow for good answers, without understanding the operating principles behind them" etc

Comment: @Dukeling - understood

Comment: `helps a lot of companies weed out the programmers` Still I think there are better ways. They can ask to code something directly related to work. It can also help in weeding out programmers. Also good algorithm knowledge doesn't means you will do the job well because you will be doing something different than writing good algorithms in the job.

Comment: @VarunAgw- clearly algorithms and data structures are not the entirety of the interview. You'll be asked a variety of questions; the employers that use those are not stupid you know.

Comment: @VarunAgw, when you are a manager, you can ask whatever questions you want to try to figure out who is and is not capable of doing the job you have. The people you are interviewing have a reason for asking this and it doesn't matter what that reason is ultimately since you will have to have an acceptable answer to move through the process. But since these are questions that test your fundmental understanding of computer science, I don't see them disappearing any time soon. Maybe the weed out some potentially good people but they also  weed out most of the incompetent.

Comment: @kolossus: NSMutableArray works just fine as a stack and a queue. You add items at the end, and the only difference is whether you remove items at the end or the start. Performance is the same.

Comment: @gnasher729 "stack" and "queue" are *abstract* data types (ADTs). Your example is a concrete type that can be used within the framework of a stack or queue. The performance consideration there becomes whether you need FIFO behavior (a queue) or LIFO/FILO (a stack).

Comment: @kolossus, I love your answer for its logic and it opens me up to accepting this new way of interviewing, but its flawed. So knowing algorithms will make it easy and quick for me to learn API development? who is supposed to teach me? No tech company in the US will bother investing resources in such an endeavor, I am supposed to know, but I spent my time learning algorithms, a different problem to be solved than API development.

Comment: @Daniel - glad you found the answer useful. To your point, knowing *some* algorithms will make you a better developer *overall*; you don't need to know every algo in the book. Flawed or not, that's just the reality of recruiting for a decent software shop. They expect you to know the fundamentals (not even the really fancy stuff like the more esoteric trees) *before* you come to work for them.

Comment: @kolossus, my gut feeling tells me that once enough of us are learning and passing these algo tests, they are going to move the cheese again to a new trend. So, I guess my big picture point being that if most shops did this because of the reason you give, it would be acceptable to me, but I agree that most companies are doing it just because other companies are doing it. The clue is in those companies that never bother to ask me the why? I chose the answer I did, the ones that give you a Codility/Hackerrank link and send you on your way.

Answer (score 17):

- **Can you write working code?**

  This is of course assuming you're actually asked to write actual code in the interview (white-board style).

  This isn't so much about not even having a single typo in your code, but more about just knowing what basic constructs like for-loops look like, knowing how to put the bits together and proving that you've actually written a bit of code in a language to know most of the most common methods / classes (apparently interviewers have a bit of a problem with candidates that can't even pass [the fizz buzz test](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FizzBuzzTest)).
- **Can you think through a problem?**

  This definitely doesn't just apply to algorithms.

  You need to be able to understand the problem, analyse the requirements, pick appropriate data structures and algorithms, write the code / walk through the approach, and analyse it - that's required for many / most (non-bug-fix) programming tasks.
- **Can you communicate well (about programming)?**

  Do you understand the problem as described?

  Do you ask for clarification when required?

  Can you explain the high-level approach before you start writing the code?

  Are you able to explain your code after the fact?

  The ability to communicate well is important in your day-to-day job as a programmer.

  Your boss shouldn't be concerned that you're not going to be able to understand the explanation of a problem, not ask for clarification when things are unclear (and just make some radical assumptions), have no ability to walk through how you're planning to solve any given problem and/or have no ability to explain code you've written to anyone else.
- **Do you have a decent knowledge of data structures and algorithms?**

  While you may be asked about an advanced data structure or algorithm that you'll never use, knowledge of this data structure may be a fairly accurate indicator that you know pretty much all the basic ones quite well.

  I'm also fairly sure you can stick to simple data structures or algorithms (linked-list, array, binary search tree, binary search, etc.) in many cases and still do well in this specific aspect - while an advanced data structure or algorithm may be better suited to solve the problem at hand, you could often fairly efficiently solve the problem with a combination of basic ones - there's still picking between them based on appropriateness and combining them appropriately.

  And you definitely need a decent knowledge of data structures and algorithms - you can't be good at what you do if you don't know when to use which tools in your toolbox.
- **Can you analyse time and space complexity and weigh choices up against each other with them in mind, making the most appropriate choice for the situation?**

  Any data structure or algorithm question should involve complexity, and it will be very significant to your day-to-day job - no-one wants you to, for example, write code that endlessly does linear search through a large unchanging array because you don't know what's going on on the low level.

Answer (score 7):

I do technical interviews. I very often do not ask the people at all about the stuff they will be doing, but about loosely related stuff they have been doing. The rationale behind  this is simple:

- I can see how deep the person likes to go into technical details.
- I can compare the person to their peers
- I can test his analytic strength better on something where he actually knows something about that some unknown thing.
- I see also the self-reflection and team skills. E.g. when a CS person talks about their master thesis and explicitly states that they left a certain part to do for a team mate - or how they took ownership of something

All of this only can work if I present them with something which I actually can expect them to know. If they are good in these things, then usuually they are also good in other topics.

Comment: you are a very sensible technical interviewer and very wise. I do not dismiss the kolossus provides as it makes a lot of sense as well. There is one small detail that kolossus misses. Writing an algorithm solves a very specific problem, CRUD functionality solves a very specific problem. How are they connected? In other words, if I learn the former, will that lead to an intuitive understanding of the latter?

Answer (score 6):

There are probably two main answers:

Firstly, because it's an opportunity to see how a candidate approaches a problem. Even if you don't know the specific solution to the problem immediately, how you explain how you would approach the problem may be revealing about your ability to think clearly, to understand the problem, and demonstrate other qualities like patience.

The second answer is that they are just doing it because it is a way of demonstrating how much a candidate knows, and that they believe other companies do the same, and so the question acts as a fairly arbitrary hurdle that they want candidates to jump over.

Comment: Quite often it is a way of recruiting people just like me and also some times a way of using ones credentials as a form of dominance behaviour.

Comment: @James, the algorithm tests one company had me take thus far, was just a here go take this test on Codility and go away forever. No one ever got back in touch with me to ask me why I wrote the algorithms the way I did. They just saw that not all my solutions were 100% correct, so they said, well we want the guy that gets 100% on it and that's that.

Comment: @Daniel I'm sorry you had that experience. It sounds like you're better off not working for that company, if that's how they treat people!

Comment: @JamesAdam, to be clear they did not actually say that to me. The point is that a lot of companies are looking for that easy way around having to actually go through a 100 applicants. So they have found that they will grab Codility or Hackerrank and just give everyone a boilerplate algorithm tests that they themselves have no clue about and look for the candidate who gets 100%. But I agree I and others are better off not working for such a company.

Answer (score 0):

Author asked: "why they check algorithms , even if the work does not require them"

In most of cases, because:

1) it is the easiest way for an immature programmer, fresh from a uni or just good "googler",  to argument with a candidate, who knows more than an interviewer.

2) because of unawareness of the complexity of modern high level languages and their APIs.

When they ask algorithms - they think they "check how a candidate thinks".

After 20 years of programming, you naturally forget most of that algorithms material from an university, because it is rarely used in the low-level way.

(Exception: C/Assembly programmers in some layers, language core programmers, data mining)

You more frequently concentrated on APIs and high level data structures.
Plus concurrency language features, design patterns, dark corners of object oriented and functional styles ARE far more important in 80% of programmers jobs, so you naturally keep them in memory. 80% of programmers start recall/refresh algorithms knowledge only for interviews. This is the reality.

So, you asked about "what your interviewer knows or able to google", not about "what the job requires", job real requirement might be a very dark secret for your interviewer!!!

Modern API, concurrency issues, and high level data structures are ten/hundreds times more complex than school algorithms and the requirement to know all that constantly is insane.

So, you actually asked "the safer part", things that your interviewer able to scratch form the web-pages,

non-algorithmic part may be 1000 time more complex, but it is why you rarely asked that part - interviewer is afraid  - here experience required, not only "googling".

In my view, industry is paralyzed by those  interviewers, most of them are team-leads that got into their position after too short programmer career.

Those questions are a trademark of ignorance and insufficient experience.

Instead of asking 10 questions in each of 10 areas of programming that this company/position involved, for example, design patterns, concurrency, protocols, web, concurrency ,client, server, UML, frameworks, etc... ( 100 questions is a minimum to have a broad view) to discover all weak and strong sides of an candidate, they usually start their interview that way:

"I usually ask only two questions!". (It is obligatory followed by very narcissistic look -  note that -  like this guy discovered a secret of a good interview and never bothers with many other questions!) One question will be a puzzle, second - algorithm. It is enough! This is what really important for a job - puzzle cracking and a memory from your school days!!!

That just means: "I think I'm smart, because I googled that a week ago, read solution and understood it, now is your turn, you have 10 minutes, but no google".

You can tell "do not exaggerate, people know what they ask".
Really? You really think if I will ask another "puzzle" back I will get the clear answer?

In my view, interviewer must make an effort to ask what he able to do him/herself, not less, but not more. Otherwise  - it is a circus, the sole purpose of which is to build up some other ego on an account of the candidate.

That leads to an advance of a fresh, puzzle loving, but in the practice weak guy, in opposite, the working horse that knows 1000 times more, but less concentrated on a puzzling aspect will usually fail - a good memory rarely keeps the impression junk, that you can google, good "operative" memory keeps day-to-day issues.(Except , as I said, certain fields,where algorithms -ARE day-to-day business, not about them the question asked here!)

I would demand algorithms only in fields where they are requirement for a job, not for each programmer job.

BTW, such "two questions" basis is a Klondike for outsourcing companies.

They usually send a "probe" guy to discover those questions, and then a "real candidate" , who will finally answer them (after good googling).

I know that for sure - that way those funny questions usually cracked and the actual job also gets done well. You can in 99% of cases have only one: good "algorithmist" OR good "languagist", not both.

That's one of the reasons why we have those outsourcing companies growing and live exceptionally well, although they give 0 value both for their workers and for companies they employed by.

Comment: That is a really great answer. I personally don't have the time to sit everyday and practice algorythms I will forget the next week. I'm better learning about patterns, architecture, DDD and other things you mentioned. The big thing I've learned while trying to memorize algorythms was Asymptotic computational complexity.

Comment: Just to complement. Understanding data structures is also a good skill in my opinion. Knowing which one to use and etc.